# Quando usamos "não" depois do verbo?

Tags: gramática, verbos

Para colocar um verbo na forma negaiva, colocamos **não** antes do verbo.

> Exemplo:
>   Eu não preciso ser reconhecido.

Mas algumas vezes colocamos **não** depois do verbo.

> Exemplo:
>   Eu preciso de ajuda não.

Estes dois casos são diferentes ou a mesma coisa?

Comment: A diferença e que o primeiro exemplo consiste em duas orações; aí a posposição da negação verbal é impossível, mesmo nas variantes onde é comum. O segundo exemplo é uma oração só, então, nas variantes onde a posposição é aceitável (Nordeste, Minas Gerais, Goiás), ela é natural (no registro coloquial; no padrão nunca).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Na língua escrita usa-se muito raramente**, a não ser que estejas reproduzindo o falar de alguém.

Já, coloquialmente, é usado em duas situações:

**Enfatizar uma negativa prévia:**

- Não, não quero, não.
- Não estou perguntando nada, não.
- Não sei não.

**E após o verbo para fazer a forma negativa.** Note que nesses casos, ao contrário do exemplo "Eu preciso de ajuda não", são geralmente **respostas curtas e o pronome pessoal é omitido**:

- 1- "Você pediu ajuda a ele?"  - "Pedi não. Exigi!
- 2- "Tu sabes onde ele está?"  - "Sei não. (regionalismo)
- 3- "Você viu meu filho?"      - "Vi não" (regionalismo)

Em algumas regiões do Brasil, os exemplos 2 e 3 são extremamente comuns (principalmente na Bahia e outros estados do Nordeste, áreas rurais de Minas Gerais, etc)

Comment: Então o meu exemplo é tipo de Enfatizar?

Comment: @Majid   Não, no teu exemplo não é para enfatizar.  É só uma forma muito incomum de se falar.  Na língua falada, recomendo que tu uses: "eu não preciso de ajuda", ou "não preciso de ajuda".

Answer (score 1):

O significado é o mesmo, mas o segundo exemplo é mais comum na língua oral ou mídias sociais.

É também comum começar com um outro "não": "não preciso de ajuda, não".

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais, grafa-se e diz-se "eu não preciso de ser reconhecido". Ditam as boas regras da sintaxe em Português, que a partícula negativa **não**, surge por norma entre o sujeito e o verbo.

> Eu não fiz o trabalho.

Como em qualquer língua indoeuropeia, com sintaxe similar, em primeiro lugar temos o sujeito, depois o verbo, ou seja, a ação, e depois então temos o complemento/objeto direto. A negação, de acordo com as boas regras da sintaxe, surge por norma, depois do sujeito e antes do verbo.

De salientar que o Português, ao contrário por exemplo do Alemão, não tem duas partículas negativas diferentes para a negação de verbos (ich habe *nicht* gemacht / eu não fiz), ou substantivos (ich habe *kein* Auto / eu não tenho carro). Em qualquer caso, mesmo nestas línguas germânicas onde existem duas palavras, quer para a negação das ações a que o verbo faz referência, quer para a referência à inexistência de substantivos, essa partícula negativa surge também, sempre antes da ação ou objeto que é negado.

Pode-se todavia, sem violar as boas regras da sintaxe, alterar a posição da partícula negativa, mas para tal, tal como refere o anterior comentador, a vírgula é obrigatória. Esta versão surge mais num contexto oral e como resposta a uma pergunta, e em duplicado, apenas para enfatizar a negação.

> Se fiz o trabalho? Não fiz, não!

Já a frase que apresenta

> Eu preciso de ajuda não.

É sintaticamente inaceitável, quer no registo oral, quer escrito. Algo como

> Não preciso de ajuda, não.

já seria aceitável do ponto de vista sintático, pois estamos, teoricamente, perante duas orações: a primeira oração que obedece às normais e corretas posições das palavras em função das suas respetivas funções sintáticas, considerando em acréscimo que em Português, o pronome pessoal enquanto sujeito pode ser prescindível; e a segunda oração, separada da primeira pela presença da vírgula, apenas com a partícula negativa.