# "Não" no final da frase (línguas germânicas?)

Tags: gramática

Em algumas regiões do Brasil, em especial no nordeste, é comum colocar o "não" no final da frase. Similar como ocorre em línguas germânicas, como no alemão:

Exemplo 1:

- Eu gosto de gato **não**.
- Ich mag die Katze **nicht**.

Exemplo 2:

- Eu como carne de porco **não**.
- Ich esse Schweinefleisch **nicht**.

Nessas regiões do Brasil usam-se também outras estruturas típicas de línguas germânicas, mudando a ordem: *SUJEITO+VERBO+OBJETO*

Qual a origem desta flexibilidade no português? É algo antigo da formação da língua portuguesa, como influência celta ou mais recente como a dominação holandesa no nordeste do Brasil (sec XVII)?

Comment: Por exemplo: Eu **não** gosto de carne,**não**. Ou no falar popular: Gosto de carne, não.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Não final.

'*Não*' na frase fornecida por você é advérbio de negação-adjunto adverbial de negação. Sabe-se que adjuntos adverbiais podem se posicionar em qualquer lugar da frase (podendo alterar significado), mas costumam ficar tipicamente antes ou depois do elemento modificado, ou no fim da frase. Diferentemente do adjunto adnominal, que deve ficar sempre ao lado do elemento principal.

'*Não*' no fim da frase pode ser usado para ênfase — especialmente em respostas —, ou pode ser regionalismo (de MG, inclusive, que não teve intenso influxo de germânicos, mais de portuguêses, italianos e africanos).

[A pergunta, em realidade, já foi respondida aqui.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/quando-usamos-n%C3%A3o-depois-do-verbo)

### 2. Inversão sintática

A língua portuguesa, dentre várias outras coisas, é uma língua latina; a ordem SVO, portanto, pode ser alterada para aquela que lhe convier, dadas as restrições de estrutura. Veja alguns exemplos:

- objeto direto:

> SVO: eu ajudo crianças. SOV: eu crianças ajudo. OVS: crianças ajudo
>   eu. OSV: crianças eu ajudo. VSO: ajudo eu crianças. VOS: ajudo
>   crianças eu.

- objeto indireto:

> SVO: eu assisto a ele. SOV:eu a ele assisto. OVS: a ele assisto eu.
>   OSV: a ele eu assisto. VSO: assisto eu a ele. VOS: assisto a ele eu.

É claro, português é naturalmente SVO, portanto as outras — que são possíveis  (principalmente sob licença poética e por nuances particulares que se queira transmitir¹), graças ao caráter flexivo da língua — apenas soam cada vez mais estranhas, especialmente VOS (típico de idiomas austronésios).

Conclusão: não é apenas em regiões que se faz inversão sintática, é possível por padrão fazê-lo na língua; em outras regiões mais comum ou menos por questão de variações diatópicas, porventura por influência de falantes de outras línguas.

---

¹ "De você eu gosto" tem indicações diferentes de "Eu gosto de você". A primeira enfatiza o "*De você*", insinuando um "... mas não dele(a).", o segundo é uma declaração normal.

Answer (score 1):

"Eu gosto não" está incorrecto.

O "não" no final da frase é adicionado apenas para ênfase e, no caso, penso que advém da expressao "eu não gosto, não", tendo posteriormente sido encurtada para "gosto não", "como não", "falo não"...

Penso que esse jeito de falar tem mais a ver com a descontracção do falante do que com influências germânicas...